# Do you need to close files when opened and read to compare in an "if" statement?

Tags: python

```
if open(file1).read() == open(file2).read():
    print('match')
```

Do I need to close these files after comparing them? I know I need to when doing the following, but is this different?

```
target = open(file1)
```

Comment: It's no different.

Comment: `open(file1).read()` is equivalent to `temp = open(file1)` followed by `temp.read()`.

Comment: CPython might usually let you get away with it, but you really should use a `with` statement to control closing the file.

Answer (score 5):

In both cases you describe (named or unnamed file objects), failing to explicitly `close` the file will work (mostly) deterministically on the reference interpreter, known as CPython (since it is reference counted), but behave non-deterministically on alternate interpreters (almost all of which are garbage collected, not reference counted, so the cleanup may not happen, or may be delayed arbitrarily). Even when assigning to a name like `target`, on CPython, the implicit close will usually occur as soon as the function in question returns (barring the open file becoming involved in a reference cycle which can delay the cleanup indefinitely).

Best practice is to always use `with` statements, whether or not you would have assigned to a name, to get guaranteed deterministic cleanup on all Python interpreters:

```
with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    if f1.read() == f2.read():
        print('match')
```

You still don't need to call `close` here, because the `with` statement guarantees that anything shy of a hard exit from the interpreter (e.g. by calling `os._exit` or triggering a segfault) will close the files when the flow of execution leaves the `with` block (by `return`ing, by an exception bubbling out, etc.).

Comment: Would I be able to use `copyfile` in the `with` block to copy one file to the other if they don't match?

Comment: @kysevenle: Should be possible; `shutil.copyfile` opens the files itself, so it would be unrelated to the file objects you opened yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you do**. You could also use the `with` keyword to open each file individually and get the contents to compare them. This will handle closing the file pointer for you when it leaves the scope.

In your case, this would look like the following:

```
with open(file1, 'r') as f:
    content1 = f.read()
with open(file2, 'r') as f:
    content2 = f.read()

if content1 == content2:
    print('match')
```

And is explained further here:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @Graipher: Note: That feature was introduced in Python 2.7/3.1, so people on truly archaic interpreters won't have it, but frankly, if you've decided to tie your hands and keep running 2.6 or earlier, that's self-inflicted pain and you deserve what you get. :-)